# Export AutoCad Layer to ESRI shapefile

Tags: c#, autocad, shapefile, objectarx

I need to export features from a particular layer in the Autocad2013 drawing to ESRI shapefile format. As I am using the `c#`, I have downloaded ObjectARX for Autocad. But I don't know whether any library support the direct conversion to shapefile format.

I would be thankful if anyone could provide the right suggestion to doing this.

Answer (score 0):

[NetTopologySuite](http://code.google.com/p/nettopologysuite/)(NTS) is a .Net API that is used in Gis related applications. It does contain [methods](http://code.google.com/p/nettopologysuite/source/browse/trunk/NetTopologySuite.IO/NetTopologySuite.IO.ShapeFile/ShapeWriter.cs?r=763) to export to shapefile.

The challenge here would be to convert the Autodesk Objects(AcDbPolyline etc..) to NTS type Geometries. [TF.Net](http://code.google.com/p/tf-net/) is another library that has a decent DwgReaderWriter to convert AutoCad geometries to Nts Geometries. TF.Net actually uses NTS as a reference itself so you need to take care of namespace collision. Or you could use TF.Net alone without Nts but I am not sure if TF.Net has its underlying NTS updated to the latest version.

There are some samples on using TF.Net IO [here](http://code.google.com/p/tf-net/wiki/DwgReaderWriter)

Answer (score 0):

**Try FDO export options.**

Mapguide API documentation and Autodesk Map3d developer documentation has some examples to help you. Also check the sample folder that comes along with Autodesk Map3d which has some sample applications.

**Here are some links that might be useful**
http://trac.osgeo.org/fdo/browser/trunk/Providers/SHP/Managed/UnitTest/ProviderTests/SelectTests.cs

http://trac.osgeo.org/fdo/browser/trunk/Providers/SHP/Managed/UnitTest/ProviderTests/UpdateTests.cs

http://osgeo-org.1560.n6.nabble.com/Shapefile-and-spatial-context-td3900324.html

Answer (score 0):

Mapexport via AutoCAD Civil 3D will do the trick or give the ARCGIS for AutoCAD a look it is a free Plugin that allows for sharing of AutoCAD linework with ESRI Data Layers